# Python check a list of dict if it is in correct order or got extra dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

```
a=[{'post':'up', 'address':1, 'index':96},
   {'post':'up', 'address':1, 'index':97},
   {'post':'up', 'address':1, 'index':98},
   {'post':'down', 'address':1, 'index':96},
   {'post':'down', 'address':1, 'index':98},
   {'post':'down', 'address':1, 'index':97},
   {'post':'down', 'address':1, 'index':99}]
```

this is my list of dictionary for which i need to check the pair of up/down.

1. for every up, there will be a down with the same address and index.
2. the order of down dict need to follow the order of up dict - which follow the order of index (up index:96,97,98 meanwhile down index: 96,**98,97**,99)

here what i wrote. it will check the post - if it is up, it will put into a list_up and then being compared with down's address and index. if it is correct, it will pop the list_up.

next, it will check the length of list_up to determine if got extra down or not

```
list_up=[]
for item in a:
    if item['post'] == 'up':
        list_up.append(item)
    else:
        print('1 >>', list_up[0]) #for debug purpose
        print('2 >>', item) #for debug purpose
        if list_up[0]['address'] != item['address'] or list_up[0]['index'] != item['index'] :
            # print(queue_in_cmd[0])
            print(item)

        else:
            list_up.pop()
            print(True) #for debug purpose

if len(list_up) == 0:
    print('got extra down post')
```

Below is my output for which the looping is not in correct order.

```
1 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 96}
2 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 96}
True
1 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 96}
2 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 98}
{'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 98}
1 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 96}
2 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 97}
{'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 97}
1 >> {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 96}
2 >> {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 99}
{'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 99}
```

my desired output is to make the code to return only **{'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 98}** as the down dictionary has index that appear earlier than it supposed to appear. and  also return **got extra down post** because it has extra down

p/s: sorry my description is so confusing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @timgeb i already put my desired output and amend my description. hope it is not confusing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
a = [{'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 96},
     {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 97},
     {'post': 'up', 'address': 1, 'index': 98},
     {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 96},
     {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 98},
     {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 97},
     {'post': 'down', 'address': 1, 'index': 99}]
u = []
d = []
for _a in a:
    (_ := u if _a['post'] == 'up' else d).append(_a['index'])

if u == d:
    print('Everything looks good')
elif len(u) == len(d):
    print('Out of order')
elif len(u) > len(d):
    print('Too many up')
else:
    print('Too many down')
```

Comment: Hi @BrutusForcus . i cant seem to understand this line **(_ := u if _a['post'] == 'up' else d).append(_a['index'])**

Comment: This utilises the so-called "walrus operator" that's available from Python 3.8+